# Run IIS Windows container

Tags: iis, docker, containers

I have followed this (IIS Windows Container) https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/ and am running into this (Not authorised) https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21558 is it just me? Am i doing something wrong? Or does this just not work yet?

I'm running Windows 10 (Build 14931) in VM Ware with Docker beta 1.12.2-Beta28

ps I don't have enough rep to create windows-containers as a tag...

Answer (score 4):

No the Docker image is fine on Win10 - you may be hitting the loopback problem, where you can't connect via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` because of a [limitation in the Windows network stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/container_networking#default-nat-network).

Try this:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name iis microsoft/iis
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}' iis
```

The second line will give you the NAT IP address of the container, and you should be able to browse to `http://{container-ip}` and see the IIS welcome page.

Incidentally, if you're using the VM just to work with Docker, you'd be better off using Windows Server 2016 - you can use Windows Server Containers instead of Hyper-V Containers, and they're quite a bit faster to start.

Comment: Thanks I am doing docker run -d -p 80:80 --name iis microsoft/iis

Comment: That's fine - when you `docker ps` is the container running? If so, can you see the site if you browse to the container's IP address?

Comment: Sorry i guess I haven't been clear, I follow the steps including docker inspect go to the IPADDRESS:PORT ( I did the same using 2016 btw) but I get 403 - Forbidden.

Comment: Wierdly I get IIS welcome screen if I browse to the IP on port 80

Comment: This is my docker file - I'm running docker  -d -p 8000:8000 

FROM microsoft/iis

RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"]  
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"]

RUN mkdir C:\site

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    Import-module IISAdministration; \
    New-IISSite -Name "Site" -PhysicalPath C:\site -BindingInformation "*:8000:"

EXPOSE 8000

ADD content/ /site

Comment: I did it previously (with the same result) without the install .Net 4.5 then realised that might be the issue

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET app you're running? You probably need a few more things - check [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/sixeyed/nerd-dinner/blob/dockerize-part1/docker/Dockerfile) as an example.

Comment: Yes its a file new .net app from Visual Studio (just trying to test the concept)

Comment: I get "Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction : INSTALL-FEATURE" when trying some of your docker file cmds

Comment: Have a closer look at the Dockerfile - it uses `SHELL` to switch the command shell to PowerShell. See also [Windows, Dockerfiles and the Backtick Backslash Backlash](https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-dockerfiles-and-the-backtick-backslash-backlash/).

Comment: Thanks @Elton I've think I know what the issue is now. Essentially and I don't know how it works in your nerd dinner clone. but I think it was this "COPY application c:\site" that fixed it in the end.

Comment: Yep, `COPY` adds the site content from the host (where you run `docker build`) into the image, and it needs to be copied to the location where IIS is configured to run the site. In Nerd Dinner it's the final line: `COPY nerd-dinner c:\nerd-dinner`.

Comment: Again perhaps I'm not being clear in nerd-dinner it looks like your folder structure is

nerd-dinner\docker\dockerfile

which (to me) means that you would have to have

COPY ..\..\..\nerd-dinner c:\nerd-dinner

but I guess I'm wrong? or have you sym linked?

Answer (score 3):

For future me / people having the same issue. Firstly definitely follow [Elton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4502597/elton-stoneman)'s advice the links provided make for a much better dockerfile / experience when building the container. However the issue (for me) was that I don't think I was copying / adding the files to the build. {Oops} Still not clear what magic is done on the [Nerd-dinner](https://github.com/sixeyed/nerd-dinner/blob/dockerize-part1/docker/Dockerfile) clone so that it imports the correct files but that gav e the hint I needed

https://github.com/sixeyed/nerd-dinner/blob/dockerize-part1/docker/Dockerfile
https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-dockerfiles-and-the-backtick-backslash-backlash/

Comment: Thanks, the Nerd Dinner dockerization project is meant to help people on the same journey with their own apps. [Part 1](https://blog.sixeyed.com/dockerizing-nerd-dinner-part-1-running-a-legacy-asp-net-app-in-a-windows-container/) covers running an existing ASP.NET app in Docker.